# Frequency Shift of the Cavity Resonance Due to the Leakage of the Cavity

Tags: electromagnetism, optics, frequency, cavity-qed, laser-cavity

I have a question regarding planar cavity (or any other cavity) resonance. From my understanding it is true that if the cavity walls are almost perfectly reflective, then the resonance frequencies will have a very sharp peak in the frequency spectrum. If the cavity is leaky, the resonances will have a Lorentzian shape, and the bigger the leakage, the broader the spectrum.

How about the frequency shift? Is it true that cavity leakage could induce shift to resonance frequencies as well? And the larger the leakage, the larger would be the frequency shift. If it is true, how one would approach to derive the relation?

Comment: Not that I know of. As you stated the width is proportional to the finesse (how reflective the surfaces are) and the location of the maximum is proportional to the distance between them. I do not how a cavity (being passive) could achieve a frequency shift.

Comment: There are a lot of papers about leaky modes of cavities. Is your cavity dielectric?

Comment: Yes, it consists of highly (but not infinite) reflective mirrors.